# How to call another method that import to another class?

Tags: oop, dart, flutter

I want to call `three` class method that imported to `two` class file from the `one` class method.

I have tried but it's error.

File Name: one.dart

```
import 'two.dart';

class one{
  main(){
    return two().three().add();
  }
}
```

File Name: two.dart

```
import 'three.dart';

class two extends one{
  static three   = new three();
}
```

File Name: three.dart

```
class three extends two{
  void add(int a, int b){

  }
}
```

I want to call `add` method from class `one`. How to do that? Please help?

Comment: in file one.dart , there appears to be a spelling mistake, instead of `three()` you are using `tree()`. also post the error you are getting.

Comment: Can you post the log?

Comment: I couldn't see the log. What I can see is three() class and add() method is not shown when type (.) after class two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `three` is a static. `two().three()` => `two.three()`
2. `three` is a attribute.  `two.three()` => `two.three`
3. missed parameters of the `add` method.   `add()` => `add(1, 2)`   // Just I added any number as an example
4. `three` attribute name and `three` class name were same.   `class three` => `class Three`
5. missed type of three.   `static three` => `static Three three`

   ```
   class one{
     main(){
       return two.three.add(1, 2);
     }
   }

   class two extends one{
     static Three three = new Three();
   }

   class Three extends two{
        void add(int a, int b){
      }
   }
   ```

But, For Good OOP, There is the Dependency Inversion Principle what high-level modules should not depend on low-level modules.
Your code broke this principle now. So, I do not recommend current your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's solved now. By the way, I'm going to create a library that will handle general function on application, so I need to break into several file to make it more maintainable. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DevelopmentFlazHost Great. You got solution. You right. Absolutely, For the maintainability is important for SW.   So, I mentioned DIP. Have a nice day.

Comment: @DevelopmentFlazHost  And, Please select the answer if it is correct. It's my 1st answer for dart.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. But how to pick your answer to be selected answer? Sorry I'm new on delivering question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @DevelopmentFlazHost  You can select `V` mark below of `0` number beside of the answer what means counts voted up.    Or, Try to vote up to press up arrow above of '0' number beside of the answer.

Comment: I have clicked checklist icon under arrow, now it's colored green. But I can't click up arrow because it need at least 15 reputation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DevelopmentFlazHost   Yes. Right, You can't both of them before you get 15 reputations.   Thank you very much.   Good day~!